# Android: Error when running app from Google Play - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, google-play

When trying to run the latest version of AnkuLua in the Google Play I get the following error:

```
Runtime error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/core/CvException
stack traceback:
[C]: in functon 'exists'
?" in function 'exists'
/sdcard/AnkuLua/SW/lib/commonLib.lua:27: in function 'autoResize'
...card/AnkuLua/SW/SWScript.lua:8: in main chunk
```

The app worked correctly with my the default OS, but the default OS is way too slow.
The error occurs after installing CyanogenMod 10.1.3 Stable (Latest version that would install correctly).

As I'm not the developer of this app, I can't go into the code and try fixing it the ways I've been able to find, I was wondering that seeing as it works on other devices and OS, if there was some way I could fix this.

Device: Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (GT-P3110)

If any more information is needed, feel free to ask

Comment: Is there a way to update the OpenCV library on the device? I noticed that the version they use on the app is different to the one I have on my device, and I would assume that this is causing the error.